# How to get value of input field from a form in a script

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to display a value from a form in a script using `console.log()` for troubleshooting purposes but it seems to not be working. Here is my script.
Is there something I am missing?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var user = jQuery('#id').val;
    var file = jQuery('#custom-file-input').val;
    console.log(file);
});
```

```php
echo "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='test_ajax'>";
echo "<select name='id' id='form-option' class='test-only'>";
echo '<option selected="selected">' .'Choose a User'. '</option>';

foreach ($registeredUsers as $key => $value) {
    $registered = JFactory::getUser($value);
    echo '<option value="'.$registered->id.'">'.$registered->name.'</option>';a
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<input name='uploadedfile' type='file' id='custom-file-input' class='test-only' /> <br/>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="custom-submit-input">';
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: use like **$('#custom-file-input').val()**

Comment: There is no element with `id = 'id'`. And `val` is function, use `val()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `val()` to get the `value` of an element.

```
var user = jQuery('#id').val
```

Should be

```
var user = jQuery('#form-option').val();
```

1. Notice `()` of `val`
2. The id of element is `form-option`, `id` is the name of the `dropdown`.

Comment: This is downvoted when it is not edited. Now this is fine.